# Unable to find module 'path-to-regexp'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am trying to use the library `path-to-regexp` in my typescript project but for some reason, it isn't allowing me to import it. I used `npm install path-to-regexp --save` with and without the `--save` to try to get it working but that didn't change anything.

My `package.json` says that I do have it installed (`"path-to-regexp": "^6.1.0"`) so it confuses me why vscode would say that it can't find it.

Looking in the node_modules folder I do have path-to-regex installed there. I even tried deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then running  `npm i` but that didn't change anything.

I am trying to import it with es2015 modules as `import * as pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp'`

Comment: There seems to be no problem here. I just tested it out and everything works fine in VSCode (I've created a new empty node project, added `"path-to-regexp": "^6.1.0"` as dependency and then created a `.js` file with the line `import * as pathToRegexp from 'path-to-regexp';` and a log statement `console.log(pathToRegexp);`) Visual Studio Code does not throw a warning/error.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 that's really weird. I have no clue why my vscode is having so much trouble

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
The structure of the module causes problems with typescript's import system have two different dist folders.

```
│   History.md
│   LICENSE
│   package.json
│   Readme.md
│
├───dist
│       index.d.ts
│       index.js
│       index.js.map
│       index.spec.d.ts
│       index.spec.js
│       index.spec.js.map
│
└───dist.es2015
        index.js
        index.js.map
        index.spec.js
        index.spec.js.map
```

All I had to do was choose one of them with the typescript config:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "path-to-regexp": ["node_modules/path-to-regexp/dist/index"]
    }
  }
```

**EDIT 2.0!!!!!**
The easy fix is just to set the compiler option `"moduleResolution": "node"`